# Kendo chart display issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

[image]I have a kendo-chart with the below Json data sample.I have to show the data like in the two X- Axis one with Iron Type and other with manufacturer.Let me explain with an example. I have iron types as Swivel and Adapter.And manufacturers as SPM and FMC. Now in the X-axis under Swivel Iron type i have to show FMC ans SPM bar chart against Total Failed,Total passed and Total Processed. and one line chart based on percentage.

Can anyone help me on this how to achieve with the below data.

```
[
  {"IronType":"Adapter","Manufacturer":"FMC","TotalFailed":56,"TotalPassed":1016,"TotalProcessed":1072,"FailedVTotalInspected":5.22},
  {"IronType":"Adapter","Manufacturer":"SPM","TotalFailed":36,"TotalPassed":613,"TotalProcessed":649,"FailedVTotalInspected":5.55},
  {"IronType":"Swivel","Manufacturer":"FMC","TotalFailed":984,"TotalPassed":5094,"TotalProcessed":6078,"FailedVTotalInspected":16.19},
  {"IronType":"Swivel","Manufacturer":"SPM","TotalFailed":299,"TotalPassed":1051,"TotalProcessed":1350,"FailedVTotalInspected":22.15}
]
```

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are looking for?

Comment: How can i add the image?

Comment: Click the image button in the editor and drag your image onto the popup. Or post the image at any image sharing site and provide a link to that image.

Comment: I have added the image.

Answer (score 1):

Given your json data, you can filter for the IronType you want to display in the dataSource object:

```
var dsCertpData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: theData,
    filter: { field: "IronType", operator: "eq", value: "Swivel" }
}); 

      $("#chart1").kendoChart({
        theme: "Fiori",
        dataSource: dsCertpData,
        legend: {
          position: "right",
          visible: true,
        },
        seriesColors: ["#95B3D7","#C3D69B","#D99694","#7D60A0"],
        series: [
          {
            type: "column",
            categoryField: "Manufacturer",
            field:"TotalProcessed",
            name: "Total Processed",
            axis: "Main",
          },
          {
            type: "column",
            categoryField: "Manufacturer",
            field:"TotalPassed",
            name: "Total Passed",
            axis: "Main"
          },              {
            type: "column",
            categoryField: "Manufacturer",
            field:"TotalFailed",
            name: "Total Failed",
            axis: "Main"
          },              
          {
            type: "line",
            categoryField: "Manufacturer",
            field:"FailedVTotalInspected",
            name: "% failed",
            axis: "percent",
          }        
        ],
        categoryAxis: {
            title: { text: "Swivel" },
            axisCrossingValues: [ 10, 0],
        },
        valueAxes: [
          {
                name: "percent",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
          },
          {
                name: "Main",
          }, 
        ], 
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            template: "${series.name} : ${value}"
        }
    });
```

Then each time a new IronType is selected, update the chart:

```
    var value = $("#IronTypeFilter").val();
    dsCertpData.filter( { field: "IronType", operator: "eq", value: value });

    var chart = $("#chart1").data("kendoChart");
    chart.options.categoryAxis.title.text = value;
    chart.redraw();
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IbuDE)**

Comment: If I redraw the previous data will not be there right?

Comment: Also it is multi select box for the iron types

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty, if multiselect, perhaps you can do it this way: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IbuDE

Comment: If you get some other idea please let me know?

Comment: Hi Ezanker; If possible please help on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524690/kendo-chart-series-defaults

Comment: Hi Ezanker, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012520/kendo-bar-chart-with-texture-pattern please help me on this thread

Comment: Hi Ezanker, could you please help me on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278726/pdf-embeded-in-html-page-scroll-bar-issue