# kendo window with minimize and maximize

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I have two kendo windows one below the other in the page with minimize and maximize options. When I close or minimize the first window the window below should come up. Could you please help me achieve this?

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
<div id="dialog1"></div>

<script>
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  animation: {
    close: false
  }
});
$("#dialog1").kendoWindow({
  animation: {
    close: false
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>

$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  animation: {
    close: false
  },
  close: function(e) {
      var d1 = $("#dialog1").data("kendoWindow");
      d1.open();
  },
  minimize: function(e) {
      var d1 = $("#dialog1").data("kendoWindow");
      d1.open();
  }

});
$("#dialog1").kendoWindow({
  animation: {
    close: false
  }
});
</script>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-open

Comment: Hi Steve, I know this minimize and maximize the issue is when i minimize or close the first window i want the second window to come to the top,but curently if i close the first window it showing blank space over there

Answer (score 0):

Use the [toFront()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-toFront) method

```
$("#dialog1").kendoWindow({
  animation: {
    close: false
  },
    actions: [
        "Pin",
        "Minimize",
        "Maximize",
        "Close"
    ],
    minimize: function(e) {
      var d1 = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
      d1.toFront();
  },
    close: function(e) {
      var d1 = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
      d1.toFront();
  }
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/zBRkJj)**

Comment: Hi Ezanker thank you so much for the update but i want the this kendo windows one below the another so that if i minimize the first one the second will come to the top.Could you please help me on this

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty, are you saying that you don't want the window to minimize, just go behind the other without minimizing?

Comment: Initially I want to display two windows one below another when I minimize or close first window the second window should fill that empty area

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty i still don't understand. Do you want the second window to maximize when the first is minimized? The demo I made already brings it to the top...

Comment: In the example you made the second window is hiding in the back of first window. But what I need is user should see both windows one below another when he minimize or close first window the second window should come to top

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty, Are you talking about cascading the windows like in this picture: http://blogs.mathworks.com/images/pick/jiro/potw_cascade/cascade_screenshot.png

Comment: could please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278726/pdf-embeded-in-html-page-scroll-bar-issue?noredirect=1#comment73626308_43278726