# PDF Embeded in html page scroll bar issue

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have emdeded a pdf into my page using object. Its working fine in chrome, but in IE i am getting an issue like when i scroll the page it is overlapping with the panel as shown in the attached image.

```
<object data="@Url.Action("ViewDisclosure","ProviderEnrollment")" 
    type="application/pdf" style="z-index:9" width="90%" height="400"></object>
```

[image]

Comment: could you please post the code?

Comment: I have already added <object data="@Url.Action("ViewDisclosure","ProviderEnrollment")" 
    type="application/pdf" style="z-index:9" width="90%" height="400"></object>

Comment: This is most likely being caused by JavaScript (and CSS related to that JavaScript) that displays this modal that the PDF is shown in. We would need more information on that.

Comment: Asking same question with different title is not a good practice.

Comment: @Chris what kind of information u need? Actually i didnt display this as modal pop up i have embeded this in a panel when i scroll the pdf is overlapping with menu as shown in image. Also please note its not happening in chrome only in IE.

Comment: Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Team can some one help me on this

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/codepen that duplicates the issue?

Comment: Hi ezankar, to create a fiddler it need lot code like master page so many cad to be included not sure how can share this

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue with the simplest code possible and then share the code. If we can't reproduce it, we can't help...

Comment: open the below plunker in Chrome and IE you will see the difference http://plnkr.co/edit/JmiFF8jIKoBVQbfrPIor?p=preview similar thing is happening to me

Comment: @Ezanker Have you got chance to look at this?

Comment: Not perfect, but placing an empty iframe under the fixed header seems to help: http://plnkr.co/edit/lYBlAq?p=preview  still see flashes of pdf above, but when stop scrolling, hear is above....

Comment: ya i also tried the same but still that flickering effect was coming is there any way this issue can be fixed? do you have any idea on this?

Comment: i have no other ideas