# Kendo bar chart with texture pattern

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

[image]I have a kendo bar chart as below. But instead of colors i need to show as some line or dots pattern. Can someone help me on this.

I have the datasource for the chart. Then I am binding that data to datasource. How will i assign the patters? Could you please help me on this

```
 $("#NumActivitiesChart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Number of Activities Report",
            font: "bold 20px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
            color: "brown"
        },
        //plotArea: {
        //    background: "#EAEFFA"
        //},
        dataSource: dsNumActivitiesData,
        seriesColors: colours,
        series: [{
            type: "column",
            categoryField: "ChartByName",
            field:"NumTestInstances",
            gap:5
        }],

        valueAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Number of Activities",
                font: "bold 15px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
                color: "brown"
            }
        },

        categoryAxis:{
            title: {
                text: "@Model.Filters.NumActivitiesChartBy",
                font: "bold 18px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
                color: "brown"
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            template: "${series.name} : ${value}"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[SVG patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns)** to apply hatching as a background.

Somewhere in your HTML markup, define an svg element that includes the patterns you want to use, e.g.:

```
 <div style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern1" width="4" height="4" patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="2" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1" />
        </pattern>

        <pattern id="pattern2" width="4" height="2" patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="2" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Then when creating the chart, I give each series a unique color so I can easily get the SVG paths of the bars by that fill color. In the render even of the chart, I get the bars and change the fill to the desired pattern.

```
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            theme: "flat",
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
            },
            series: [{
                name: "S1",
                color: "rgba(150,150,150,0.999)",
                data: [10, 30, 20, 45, 60]
            },{
                name: "S2",
                color: "rgba(120,120,120,0.999)",
                data: [20, 10, 14, 56, 89]
            } ],
            valueAxis: {
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
            },
           render: function(e){                
              $('[fill="rgba(150,150,150,0.999)"]').attr("fill", "url(#pattern1)");
              $('[fill="rgba(120,120,120,0.999)"]').attr("fill", "url(#pattern2)");
            }
        });
```

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0nmfz6cd/2/)**

### **UPDATE:**

You can actually just set the series color directly to the pattern and avoid the render event:

```
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            theme: "flat",
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
            },
            series: [{
                name: "S1",
                color: "url(#pattern1)",
                data: [10, 30, 20, 45, 60]
            },{
                name: "S2",
                color: "url(#pattern2)",
                data: [20, 10, 14, 56, 89]
            } ],
            valueAxis: {
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
            },
        });
```

Updated **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0nmfz6cd/5/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot Ezanker appreciate your help

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty, you can actually get rid of the render and set the patterns directly as the series color: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0nmfz6cd/4/

Comment: Inned one morwe thing but the series column is dynamic how can i assign the patters?

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty, just have the patterns already on the page and then when you generate the series assign the patterns to the color attribute.

Comment: Hi Ezankar i have update my code could you please help me how can i assign patters in my example

Comment: @SamanthKolisetty, simplest way would be to use the seriesColors array: seriesColors: ["url(#pattern1)","url(#pattern2)"],  https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0nmfz6cd/7/

Comment: Hi Ezankar, Could you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459521/kendo-line-chart-points-issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the bar chart, you could create a line chart.  Both chart will be able to work with the same dataSource so the only thing you'll have to change set the `SeriesDefaults`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
    .Name("chart")
    .Title("Site Visitors Stats \n /thousands/")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(false)
    )
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
        .Background("transparent")
    )
    .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults => 
        seriesDefaults.Line().Style(ChartLineStyle.Smooth)
    )
    .Series(series => {
        series.Bar(new double[] { 56000, 63000, 74000, 91000, 117000, 138000 }).Name("Total Visits");
        series.Bar(new double[] { 52000, 34000, 23000, 48000, 67000, 83000 }).Name("Unique visitors");
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun")
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric()
        .Max(140000)
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi,I dont want line chart i want to fill the bars with some line or dot pattern instead of colors.Could you please let me know if you have any idea on this?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were expecting as final result, maybe you could draw an example and add it to you question.

Comment: I have added the image to my question. I want something like this

Comment: Hi, Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: I already modified the way the title was displayed...  I guess it *could* be possible to do so with the bar.  Have a look at the html generated by kendo and try to see if there's a pattern that would allow to find the bar elements.  For sure, that kind of modification ain't available out of the box and won't be supported by kendo.