# Kendo Grid Column title with red asterick to indicate required field

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am using a kendo grid with multiple columns. But i need to display few columns with red asterick to indicate required filed. Can someone help me on this.

```
<div id="failureTypeInfoGrid" style="width:100%;overflow-x:auto;">
                                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.lstSerialData)
            .Name("serialGrid")
            .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
            .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.UnitId).Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("#= UnitId #" +
                     "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].UnitId' value='#= UnitId #' />"
                   );
            columns.Bound(c => c.SerialNumber).Title("Unit No/Serial No*").ClientTemplate("#= SerialNumber #" +
                     "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].SerialNumber' value='#= SerialNumber #' />"
                   );

            columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Failure_Subjected_To, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["FailureSubjectedTo"], dataFieldValue: "ValueId", dataFieldText: "ValueName").Width(140).ClientTemplate("#= getValue(Failure_Subjected_To) #" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].Failure_Subjected_To' value='#= Failure_Subjected_To #' />"
                  ).Title("Fail Subjected To");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Hours_Before_Failure).ClientTemplate("#= Hours_Before_Failure #" +
                     "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].Hours_Before_Failure' value='#= Hours_Before_Failure #' />"
                   ).Title("Hours Before Failure (Hours)");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Failure_Temperature).ClientTemplate("#= Failure_Temperature #" +
                     "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].Failure_Temperature' value='#= Failure_Temperature #' />"
                   ).Title("Failure Temperature (Celsius)");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Component_LTC_Code).ClientTemplate("#= Component_LTC_Code #" +
                     "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].Component_LTC_Code' value='#= Component_LTC_Code #' />"
                   ).Title("Manufacturing Date/LTC Code");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Board_Ref_Designator).ClientTemplate("#= Board_Ref_Designator #" +
                     "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].Board_Ref_Designator' value='#= Board_Ref_Designator #' />"
                   ).Title("Board Ref Designator");
            columns.Bound(c => c.FailureMode).Hidden(true).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 20px;" }).ClientTemplate("#= FailureMode #" +
                     "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].FailureMode' value='#= FailureMode #' />"
                   );
            columns.Bound(c => c.FailureMechanism).Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("#= FailureMechanism #" +
                     "<input type='hidden' name='SerialData[#= index(data)#].FailureMechanism' value='#= FailureMechanism #' />"
                   );
            columns.Bound(c => c.FailureModeName).Title("Failure Mode");
            columns.Bound(c => c.FailureMechanismName).Title("Failure Mechanism");
        })

        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 200px;overflow-x:auto" })
                                            //.Scrollable()
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.Id); model.Field(p => p.FailureModeName).Editable(false); model.Field(p => p.FailureMechanismName).Editable(false); })
        )
                                    )
                                </div>
```

I want to display red asterik after unit serial number.

Comment: Please provide your code. Also provide information that where you want to show this asterisk and it would be nice if you can also provide screenshot for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. We can achieve this thing by using header template.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.SerialNumber).HeaderTemplate("Unit No/Serial No" + "<span style='color:red;'>*</span>");
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Hi Jayesh,can you help me on the below thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177391/kendo-chart-call-out-message